# HTML site navigation <!-- #include file="topnav.html" --> no longer works

Tags: html, navigation, include, footer

Suddenly, my site navigation no longer works. With no changes in the page coding made by me, my top navigation and footer (except for the home page) no longer appears on the live site, but does show as it's supposed to when I'm in Dreamweaver. I've wracked my brain and looked nearly everywhere to find a reason why, but to no avail. I haven't changed anything in the navigation code or header. I've tried a php version with no change. I've attached a screenshot from Dreamweaver to show what the topnav is supposed to look like and a second image from the live site when it was working.

[Topnav expected appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpl4A.jpg)
[Topnav as it appeared on live site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iMdQ.jpg)

```
<header id="header">
<!-- Header topnav start -->
<!-- #include file="topnav.html" -->
<!-- END topnav -->
</header>
```

I've been using this method for years and seemingly for no reason it has ceased to work. You can see the missing navigation, the homepage footer (but no longer on any other page), here:

[Blue Planet Photography current appearance](https://blueplanetphoto.com)

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: No clue? I hoped there would be some thoughts, suggestions. I'm still at a loss with this problem.